# ngrx 4 selector does not update view

Tags: angular, selector, ngrx

I want to display 'Server[]' from remote service. Currently, remote service returns only 1 record.

If I use only simple 'select', values in html page are displayed properly. 
Whenever I use it with createSelect, they are not displayed properly.

The following is my code.

reduces/index.ts

```
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  servers: server.serverReducer,
}

export interface AppState {
  servers: Server[];
}


export const selectFeatureServers = createFeatureSelector<Server[]>('servers');

export const selectServers = (state: AppState) => state.servers ;
export const selectAllServers = (state: AppState) => state.servers;

export const selectConnectedServers = createSelector(
  selectFeatureServers,
  ( servers: Server[] ) => servers.filter((server: Server) => true )
)
export const selectSummary = createSelector(
  selectFeatureServers,
  (servers: Server[]) => servers.length );
```

dev-page.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

// import { AppState } from '../_reducers/index';
import * as fromServer from '../_actions/servers';
import { Server, Nvr } from '../models';

import * as fromRoot from '../_reducers';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dev-page',
  templateUrl: './dev-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dev-page.component.scss']
})
export class DevPageComponent implements OnInit {

  private servers$: Observable<Server[]>;
  private connectedServers$: Observable<Server[]>;
  private serverCount$: Observable<number>;
  private server$: Observable<Server>;
  private count$: Observable<number>;

  constructor(private _store: Store<fromRoot.AppState>) {
    this.count$ = this._store.select('servers').map( ss => ss.length );
    this.servers$ = this._store.select(fromRoot.selectFeatureServers);
    this.connectedServers$ = this._store.select(fromRoot.selectConnectedServers);

    this.serverCount$ = this.servers$
      .do(s => console.log('do ', s.toString()))
      .map( s => {
        console.log('map ', s, ' length ', s.length);
        s.forEach( x => console.log('map2 ', x) );
        return s.length; });

    this.servers$.subscribe( s => {
      console.log('subscribed', s, s.length) ;
      s.forEach( x => console.log('map2 ', x) );
    });
    this.serverCount$.subscribe( s => console.log( 'count sub', s));
  }

  // this will fetch Server[] from my remote server 
  ngOnInit() {
    this._store.dispatch({type: fromServer.ServerActionTypes.SERVER_FETCHED});
  }
}
```

dev-page.component.html

```
<p>
  Number of Server : {{ serverCount$ | async }}
</p>

<p>
  Number of Count : {{ count$ | async }}
</p>
<p>
  Server : {{server$ | async }}
</p>
<p>
  Servers : {{ (servers$ | async).length }}
</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let server of servers$ | async ">
    Server Info : {{server.name}}, {{ server.status }}
  </li>
</ul>
<p *ngFor="let server of connectedServers$ | async ">
  Connec Server Info : {{server.name}}, {{ server.status }}
</p>
```

Remote service returns only 1 'Server' field. Html page shows following result:

```
Number of Server : 0
Number of Count : 0
Server :
Servers : 1
Server Info : SSM Server, Connected
```

Oddly, simple select works perfectly. However, if i use it with createSelect, nothing works.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I found a problem for this problem. My reducer has problems on update state. Reference for state is not chagned, and selector can't detect changes

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem for this problem. My reducer has problems on update state. Reference for state is not chagned, and selector can't detect changes

Comment: can you explain more...having same problem

Comment: You need to replace object, not update. Or you can use ngrx/entity for boilerplate.